# Probability of winning specified amount of money

Tags: probability

We play a game in which we toss a coin - if we have head we get 1\$ otherwise, we lose 1\$. Let's say we do it 50000 times. What's the probability of losing at least 10\$?
I started by calculating the excepted value of one time:
$$
x_{1} = 1
\\ x_{2} = -1
\\EX= \frac{1}{2}\cdot1 - \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 = 0
$$
So the excepted value in the whole game is $0$.
Now I don't really know what to do. Do I need to use Chebyshev's inequality? Is it OK if $EX=0$?

Comment: Do you ask probability to lose *exactly* ten dollars, or lose *at least* ten dollars?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add this. I want to calculate the probability of losing at least ten dollars.

Comment: This is not clear.  Do you mean, what is the probability that, at the end, you will have a net loss of $\$10$?  Assuming you start at $0$ I guess?  Or do you mean, what is the probability that at some point your balance will be $-10$?

Comment: I've just added some clarification, I forgot about 'at least', my bad.

Comment: You could use Chebyshev's inequality or the central limit theorem to approximate the probability, or you could compute it exactly.

Comment: @saulspatz worth noting that in this example Chebyshev will give a *terrible* bound as we are well under one standard deviation from the mean

Comment: @jlammy Yes, I answered without thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We model the coin tosses as a binomial distribution.

Let X be the number of heads, then
$$\text{X} \sim Bn( 50000, p=0.5)$$
Then we know the net value of the whole game is
$$\text{net value} = 1(\text{X}) - 1(50000-\text{X})=2\text{X} - 50000$$
To know the probability of loosing at least \$10:
$$\mathbf{P}(\text{net value} \leq -10) = \mathbf{P}(2\text{X} - 50000 \leq -10)= 
\mathbf{P}(\text{X} \leq 24995)  ≈ 0.483947$$
Various methods can be used to calculate this final value. I chose to use wolfram alpha as a calculator but for a more laborious method  you could approximate to the normal distribution and then use a table.

Answer (score 1):

The key word here is the **binomial distribution**. The standard presentation is that if you flip a $p$-coin $N$ times, and count the number $X$ of heads, then the distribution is
$$\mathbb P(X=k)=\binom{N}{k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k}.$$
We write $X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(N,p)$ to indicatte that $X$ has this distribution.

Your profit $X$ after $50000$ tosses isn't quite $\operatorname{Bin}(50000,1/2)$ though, since we subtract when the coin comes up tails. If $Y\sim\operatorname{Bin}(50000,1/2)$, then it should be clear that $X=2Y-50000$.

So then $X\leq-10\iff Y\leq24995$. Then
$$\mathbb P(Y\leq24995)=\sum_{k=0}^{24995}\mathbb P(Y=k)=\sum_{k=0}^{24995}\binom{50000}{k}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{50000}.$$
This sum is obviously not tractable by hand. Most scientific calculators would have some kind of function that computes the CDF for a binomial random variable. You should get $0.484$ as the probability, which seems reasonable -- just a smidgen under half.